# Docker skip project on build

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have dockerfile with this config

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN apt-get update;apt-get install curl; apt-get -y install zip

RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"

RUN unzip awscliv2.zip

RUN ./aws/install

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.dotnet/tools"

#RUN dotnet tool install -g AWS.CodeArtifact.NuGet.CredentialProvider
#
#RUN dotnet codeartifact-creds install
#
#RUN aws codeartifact login --tool dotnet --domain monspire --domain-owner 986853728599  --repository monspire

RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet publish -c Release TooSee.Web.Host.csproj

# create the runnable container...
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
        libc6-dev \
        libgdiplus \
        libx11-dev \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/src/TooSee.Web.Host/bin/Debug/net6.0/publish/ .

ARG ENVIRONMENT
ENV ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["dotnet", "TooSee.Web.Host.dll"]
```

And try to run it via `docker build -t tooseeapi .`

But for reasons it skipped `.Core` project

Here is log

> => ERROR [builder 9/9] RUN dotnet publish -c Release TooSee.Web.Host.csproj                                       6.9s

---

> [builder 9/9] RUN dotnet publish -c Release TooSee.Web.Host.csproj:
> #15 0.750 Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.2.0+41abc5629 for .NET
> #15 0.750 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
> #15 0.750
> #15 2.054   Determining projects to restore...
> #15 2.057   Skipping project "/TooSee.Web.Core/TooSee.Web.Core.csproj" because it was not found.
> #15 2.060   Skipping project "/TooSee.Web.Core/TooSee.Web.Core.csproj" because it was not found.
> #15 2.385   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
> #15 3.150 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.302/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2066,5): warning : The referenced project '../TooSee.Web.Core/TooSee.Web.Core.csproj' does not exist. [/app/TooSee.Web.Host.csproj]

Dockerfile is under this path -  `C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\tooseeapi\src\TooSee.Web.Host`

And `.Core` is here

`C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\tooseeapi\src\TooSee.Web.Core`

But if I run `dotnet publish -c Release TooSee.Web.Host.csproj` I got no errors

Why it's skipped and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to keep your docker file at this location

```
C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\tooseeapi\src
```

and copy both project files separately. something like

```
COPY ["TooSee.Web.Host/TooSee.Web.Host.csproj", "./"]
COPY ["TooSee.Web.Core/TooSee.Web.Core.csproj", "./"]
```

Comment: Where I need to write this COPY?

Comment: first you should copy project files and do the restore and then you should copy other files before publish. take the reference from default dockerfile that is generated with asp.net core app.

Comment: It's working great with moving dockerfile  and without COPY

Comment: that is because you are copying everything in line no. 3. which could be problematic during development because if you change any file then it will invalidate the cached layer for docker and it will regenerate every time.